# Serializable with extra bytes

Tags: java, serialization

I did a test to serialize  (`long num = -999`) using `ObjectOutputStream` method `writeUnshared()` to serialize `-999`.

I deployed the source code to two different weblogic server:

1. machine 1:

   > bea 10.3.2 , Jrockit 160_14_R27.6.5-32, window server 2003
2. machine 2:

   > bea 10.3.2 , Jrockit 160_14_R27.6.5-32, window xp

and the results are different:

Result 1:

> aced00057372000e6a6176612e6c616e672e4c6f6e673b8be490cc8f23df0200014a000576616c7565787200106a6176612e6c616e672e4e756d62657286ac951d0b94e08b020000787200106A6176612E6C616E672E4F626A65637400000000000000000000007870fffffffffffffc19

Result 2:

> aced00057372000e6a6176612e6c616e672e4c6f6e673b8be490cc8f23df0200014a000576616c7565787200106a6176612e6c616e672e4e756d62657286ac951d0b94e08b0200007870fffffffffffffc19

the difference is `7200106A6176612E6C616E672E4F626A656374000000000000000000000078`, and the equivalent ascill conversion is as follow:

```
r[0][16]java.lang.Object[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]x


r = TC_CLASSDESC
X = TC_ENDBLOCKDATA

[0][16] = length of the new class description
java.lang.object = the class being describe
```

My question is, are there any setting to include or exclude the following extra bytes ?
Is there any way to make the test consistent on the two different servers?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: We store the serialize hash in our database. When we retrieve the raw value 999 from database,  we will try to serialize it and compare witness the value stored in the database to ensure the integrity of the data.

Comment: We are using Java version 6

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I do know I wouldn't depend on different machines to generate an identical hash this way.  Write a hash function of your own so that you control its value across different machines, java environments, java minor versions, etc.

Comment: i need to find out the reason the extra block of data in order to convince my boss to change the current alogorithm. i totally agree that the current hash algorithm to check data integrity doesn't seem to be foolproof, as illustrated by the problem i encountered.

Comment: point him to documentation of writeUnshared. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29

it specifically says that it's written in such a way that the object appears unique.

I'd simply choose another method of checking data integrity. E.g., store entity object's hash and compare it with live data.

Comment: The fact that the data is different is the only argument you need to your boss.

Comment: I found out that the issue is due to java.lang.Number extends java.lang.object. after writing the class description for java.lang.number, it continues to write java.lang.object, thus resulting in the extra bytes. But according to serializable rules, it should stop at java.lang.number course java.lang.object does not implement Serializable. Anyone has any idea?